# DFA that accepts even number of 0's and odd number of 1's

Tags: string, dfa

The question I have been asked is "Design a DFA accepting the set of all strings with an even number of 0’s and an odd number of 1’s on the alphabet {0, 1}."

I've tried this a few different ways but I can't seem to get it right. This is the best solution I could come up with:

[image]

Ignore the below diagram as it was a try gone wrong. The problem with my DFA is that for example when I enter 101100 into it it shouldn't be accepted but it is. And with 101011010 it isn't accepted when it should be. Not quite sure how to fix this.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would start by thinking about designing an automata that:

- accepts the simplest possible string it should accept: `"1"` and
- rejects the simplest possible string that it should reject: `""`

Comment: Thanks for your help, got the answer now I think!

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of hints that you may find helpful.

- First, design a DFA that accepts the set of all strings with an even number of 0s. Next, design a separate DFA that accepts the set of all strings with an odd number of 1s. See if you can use these two designs to inspire the design for the final answer.
- Try giving your states meaningful names instead of just calling them A, B, C, and D. For example, you could have a state named "even number of 0s, odd number of 1s".
- If you ever see two 0s in a row, then those two 0s together have no overall effect. What does this mean for your state diagram?

Comment: Thats great! Thanks, I believe I've got the answer now!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can make all the states possible in the DFA itself.
These are :
 - even 1's and even 0's
 - even 1's and odd 0's
 - odd 1's and odd 0's
 - odd 1's and even 0's

Give them some relevant names so that they can be easily identified.
What we need in this question is even 0's and odd 1's. So the second state is the Final state.
Also keep in mind that at first when there's no input (i.e., input is Epsilon) [i don't know how to write the symbol], the string will have even 0's and even 1's. That is the first state.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mcTU.jpg) is the final DFA diagram.